# Match or contrast error when passing data variable argument to for loop

Tags: r

```
settings_LOS = c(AUNMPSY2, AUNMPGE2, AUNMMED2, AUNMAHS2, AUNMRES2, AUNMSFA2)
for (setting in settings_LOS){ 
temp = subset(ltm_hospitalized, setting %in% c(1:31))
svymean(~setting, temp)
}
```

Why do I get this error when running this?

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

I've also using strings in the vector

```
settings_LOS = c('AUNMPSY2', 'AUNMPGE2', 'AUNMMED2', 'AUNMAHS2', 'AUNMRES2', 'AUNMSFA2')
```

which gives me this error

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

When I try without the loop it works fine, such as:

```
temp = subset(ltm_hospitalized, AUNMPSY2 %in% c(1:31))
svymean(~AUNMPSY2, temp)
           mean     SE
AUNMPSY2 8.4779 1.3647
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: try `subset(ltm_hospitalized, settings_LOS %in% setting)`

Comment: I'm not sure that solves the issue. I need each of the data variables to be filtered to responses from 1 to 31 then compute the mean. The last paragraph of code in my original question is an example.

Comment: I don’t understand what you wrote. You could probably give more elaboration on your question

Comment: You do not expect the settings to contain (1:31). There are no numbers so settings%in%(1:31) is false since there are no numbers in settings

Answer (score 0):

```
settings_LOS = c('AUNMPSY2', 'AUNMPGE2', 'AUNMMED2', 'AUNMAHS2', 'AUNMRES2', 'AUNMSFA2')

for (setting in settings_LOS){ 
temp = subset(ltm_hospitalized, eval(parse(text=setting)) %in% c(1:31))
print(setting)
print(svymean(~eval(parse(text=setting)), temp))
print(svyquantile(~eval(parse(text=setting)), temp, seq(.10, .90, by=.10)))
}
```

Turns out I have to wrap it in eval(parse(text=))